# form_validation->set_rules() not working properly in code igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation, registration

Im new to code igniter and trying to build a login and registration form in code igniter. So far login is ok but the registration form does not provide as it is needed. I followed a video tutorial but it didnt work out well. when i manually debug the code i realized that $this->form_validation->set_rules() is not working.
please help me out.

The view

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>LoginController/Register" method="get">
          <p><span id="sprytextfield1">
            <label for="tn">Full Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Full Name" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('full_name'); ?>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"> </span></span> <span id="sprytextfield2">
            <label for="tjt">Designation  <?php echo form_error('des'); ?><br>
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="des" value="pm">
            Project Manager                     
            <input type="radio" name="des" value="ceo">
            CEO<br>
            <input type="radio" name="des" value="dev">
            Devoloper                       </label>
            </span></p>
          <p><span>                 <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield3">
          <label for="te">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield4">
              <label for="tc">Company</label>
              <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Please Enter Your Company Name" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('company'); ?>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield5">
            <label for="tun">User Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Please Enter Your User Name" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('user_name'); ?>
            <span id="sprytextfield6">
              <label for="tpw">Password</label>
              <input class="form-control" input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield7">
                <label for="tpw2"> Confirm Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Please Re Enter Your Password" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?>
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>                 </p>
          <table width="385"  cellspacing="50px">
            <tr>
              <th width="75"> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>LoginController/Register"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"method="post">Create Account</button></a>
            </th>
              <th width="154"> <input name="Reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" >
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </form>
```

The controller

```
function Register(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    //Validation Rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name','Full Name','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|required|valid_email|callback_check_mail_Exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company','Company','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name','Username','trim|required|min_length[4]|callback_check_user_Exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|min_length[8]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Password Confirmation','trim|required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user_Exists', 'Username already exists. Please select another');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_mail_Exists', 'E-mail already registerd.');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
        $this->load->view('SignUp');
    }else{
        $this->load->model('MembershipModel');
        if($this->MembershipModel->create_member()){
            $data['account_created']='Your account has been created <br/><br/>';
            $this->load->view('loginform',$data);
        }else{
            $this->load->view('SignUp');
        }
    }

}
```

the model

```
function create_member(){
        $username=$this->input->post('user_name');

        $new_member=array(
            'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
            'e-mail' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'company' => $this->input->post('company'),
            'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
            'pwd' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'designation' => $this->input->post('des')
        );

        $insert=$this->db->insert('user',$new_member);
        return $insert;
    }

    function check_mail_Exists($email){
        $this->db->where('e-mail',$email);
        $result=$this->db->get('user');

        if($result->num_rows>0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

please help me out

Answer (score 1):

put method="post" in your view files

Answer (score 0):

Try this

view

```
<!-- <form action="<?php// echo base_url();?>LoginController/Register" method='get'> -->
<?php echo form_open(base_url('LoginController/Register'),['method'=>'post'])?>
          <p><span id="sprytextfield1">
            <label for="tn">Full Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Full Name" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('full_name'); ?>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"> </span></span> <span id="sprytextfield2">
            <label for="tjt">Designation  <?php echo form_error('des'); ?><br>
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="des" value="pm">
            Project Manager                     
            <input type="radio" name="des" value="ceo">
            CEO<br>
            <input type="radio" name="des" value="dev">
            Devoloper                       </label>
            </span></p>
          <p><span>                 <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield3">
          <label for="te">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield4">
              <label for="tc">Company</label>
              <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Please Enter Your Company Name" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('company'); ?>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield5">
            <label for="tun">User Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Please Enter Your User Name" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('user_name'); ?>
            <span id="sprytextfield6">
              <label for="tpw">Password</label>
              <input class="form-control" input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span> <span id="sprytextfield7">
                <label for="tpw2"> Confirm Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Please Re Enter Your Password" style="width:50%" ><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?>
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>                 </p>
          <table width="385"  cellspacing="50px">
            <tr>
              <th width="75"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create Account</button></a>
            </th>
              <th width="154"> <input name="Reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" >
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </form>
```

Comment: This worked. can I please know the reason this worked?

Comment: i'm removing this line `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>LoginController/Register"> `  change the form acthion and remove button action

Comment: When you use codeigniter form_open you don't need to add this `['method'=>'post']` it all ready adds it to it. If you look in firebug